# Generic Methods signature

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, data-access-layer, business-objects

I have a data access class that loads reference data. Each type of entity will execute it's own stored procedure and return a result set specific for that entity type. Then I have a method that maps the returned values from the datatable to the entity. All Entity Types have the same public properties of Code and Name how can I make this method generic to handle a type of entity? Something like this is what would presume but the properties are causing an error.

```
    private static T MapDataReaderToEntity<T>(IDataReader reader)
    {
        var entity = typeof (T);
        entity.Code = SqlPersistence.GetString(reader, "Code");
        entity.Name = SqlPersistence.GetString(reader, "Name");
        return entity;
    }
```

and I would call it with something like this.

```
_sourceSystem = MapDataReaderToEntity<SourceSystem>(_reader);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your entities implement an interface with the Code and Name properties defined, you could potentially use something like:

```
private static T MapDataReaderToEntity<T>(IDataReader reader)
    where T : IEntity, new()
{
    T entity = new T(); // typeof(T) would return the System.Type, not an instance!
    entity.Code = SqlPersistence.GetString(reader, "Code");
    entity.Name = SqlPersistence.GetString(reader, "Name");
    return entity;
}
```

Without the interface, there is no way for the compiler to know about the `Code` or `Name` properties.  You would need to revert to using Reflection or dynamic code, or some other less-than-ideal mechanism for determining these properties at *runtime* instead of at compile time.

Comment: Thanks Reed and all of you who answered they were spot on. I knew I was close just needed that little extra. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You could have an interface that defines those properties, and then have your entity classes implement that interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can add a generic constraint to your method:

```
public static T MapDataReaderToEntity<T>(IDataReader reader) where T : IEntity, new()
{
    T entity = new T();
    // More code here...
}
```

Note that you also need the `new()` constraint to actually construct the new entity; it indicates the any generic type argument will have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) to `MapDataReaderToEntity<T>` which ensures that any T implements Code and Name property setters, as well as a parameter-less constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your entities have properties `Code` and `Name`, I'd suggest having them implement an interface `ICodedEntity` with properties `Code` and `Name`, then define your method

```
private static T MapDataReaderToEntity<T>(IDataReader reader) where T : ICodedEntity, new()
{
    var entity = new T();
    ...     
}
```

then the code you have will compile.